# JavaScript variable's value is automatically unescaped

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
test('test.php?a=%3D');//alert(1)
function test(a){
    alert(a);
    if(a == 'test.php?a=%3D'){
        alert(1);
    }else{
        alert(2);
    }
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:test('test.php?a=%3D')">aaa</a > <!-- alert(2) -->
```

why two different ways get different results?
can anyone help me? 
thank you very much!

Comment: href cannot be directly JavaScript command, you need to add "javascript:" before

Comment: may be you want to use onclick() on <a> element

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I added JavaScript: but the result is same

Comment: @VikasSachdeva yes click works but I do not know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze these two scenarios:

1. `test('test.php?a=%3D');//alert(1)` 
   `test.php?a=%3D` is considered as a variable.
2. `<a href="javascript:test('test.php?a=%3D')">aaa</a > <!-- alert(2) -->`
   `test.php?a=%3D` is considered as an URL with query string and `%3D` converts to `=`. So the complete result is `test.php?a==`

That's the reason these two values are different. Again, consider the code which is shown below - `test.php?a=%3D` is considered as a variable, so result is `alert(1)`.

```
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="javascript:test('test.php?
a=%3D')"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot,  it worked, do you mean that if all the code follows href will be unescaped ?   I found <a onclick="javascript:test('test.php?a=%3D')"> did not work but <a onclick="test('test.php?a=%3D')"> works, can you tell me the difference?

Comment: Consider these three scenarios:
1.<a onclick="javascript:test('test.php?a=%3D')" href="#">some text1</a > //javascript variable, result alert(1);
2.<a onclick="test('test.php?a=%3D')" href="#">some text2</a> //javascript variable, result alert(1);
3.<a href="javascript:test('test.php?a=%3D')">some text3</a > //URL, result alert(2);

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code

Line 12

```
<a href="javascript" click="test('test.php?a=%3D'">aaa</a > <!-- alert(2) -->
```

Change this line and try

Comment: I change to onclick, and the result became same. Thanks ,but I don't know why.

Comment: What is `href="javascript"` supposed to do?

Comment: I want to call a javascript function, do you mean that this is not a good way of doing this?